# Why does CloudFront sometimes take about 10 minutes to get a new file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Here's my situation, users upload their files into an S3 bucket, and I'm using CloudFront to deliver images files.

But I found when a user upload multiple images (around 4~5 pics, all new uploads, NOT UPDATES), at least one image won't be able to display instantly through CloudFront (AccessDenied error), but after around 10 minutes, the image will be able to show up correctly. But meanwhile, if I use a VPN connection located in other place, the image will show up instantly, so I believe it should be a problem in my local CloudFront endpoint.

My S3 bucket is located in the US West 2 region (oregon).

Is this situation common? I did a Google search, but I didn't see anyone complaining about the same problem, so I'm worrying if I did something wrong.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue yourself? If yes, can you paste curl verbose outputs that fail on CloudFront, and that succeed on S3? If it is something you can't reproduce I think the only way to figure it out is contact support to check you requests

Comment: What is the Bucket Policy on your S3 bucket? Does it make everything public or does some process set that at the Object level? If you access the object direct from S3 within that 10 minutes, does it work? Your VPN experiment does suggest a location-specific issue.